# C# Linq Counting XML segments with specific values

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Fairly new to C#.
Im trying to do some calculations based on values of different fields.
I have an XML file with the following segments:

/UniversalInterchange/Body/UniversalShipment/Shipment/ContainerCollection/Container/ContainerType/Code
/UniversalInterchange/Body/UniversalShipment/Shipment/ContainerCollection/Container/Commodity/Code
/UniversalInterchange/Body/UniversalShipment/Shipment/OrganizationAddressCollection/OrganizationAddress/AddressType="ShippingLineAddress"
/UniversalInterchange/Body/UniversalShipment/Shipment/OrganizationAddressCollection/OrganizationAddress/OrganizationCode

Now, the values in the ContainerCollection can repeat (ie. I might have 20 containers of different types - like a 40REHC, 40GP, 40RE,20GP, etc)

The values in OrganizationAddressCollection can repeat per OrganizationAddress, but I only specifically what to find the OrganizationCode when the AddressType = ShippingLineAddress

What Im trying to achieve is to identify the shipping line and the count of each container size and the commodity within the container and apply a $ value to each one. something like:

Firstly, count the number of containers based on the first 2 digits (ie. 5 x 20 and 2 x 40)
then if the container commodity = XYZ and the Organizationcode is MYSHIPPING then multiply the count of 20's by $100 and multiply the count of 40's by 200)
then if the container commodity = ABC and the OrganizationCode is MySHIPPING then multiply the count of 20's by $50 and multiply the count of 40's by 100)

here's a sample of what Im working with

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><UniversalInterchange >
              <Header>
              
              </Header>
              <Body>
                <UniversalShipment >
              <Shipment>
                <ContainerCollection Content="Complete">
                  <Container>
                    <Commodity>
                      <Code>XYZ</Code>
                      <Description>PET FOODS - FROZEN</Description>
                    </Commodity>
                    <ContainerType>
                      <Code>40GP</Code>
                    </ContainerType>
                    </Container>
                        <Container>
                    <Commodity>
                      <Code>XYZ</Code>
                      <Description>PET FOODS - FROZEN</Description>
                    </Commodity>
                    <ContainerType>
                      <Code>40REHC</Code>
                    </ContainerType>
                    </Container>
                          <Container>
                    <Commodity>
                      <Code>ABC</Code>
                      <Description>PET FOODS - FROZEN</Description>
                    </Commodity>
                    <ContainerType>
                      <Code>20GP</Code>
                    </ContainerType>
                    </Container>
                </ContainerCollection>

                <OrganizationAddressCollection>
                  <OrganizationAddress>
                    <AddressType>NotifyParty</AddressType>
                    <OrganizationCode>SOMEONE</OrganizationCode>
                  </OrganizationAddress>
                 <OrganizationAddress>
                    <AddressType>ShippingLineAddress</AddressType>
                    <OrganizationCode>MyShipping</OrganizationCode>
                  </OrganizationAddress>
                  <OrganizationAddress>
                    <AddressType>SendingForwarderAddress</AddressType>
                    <OrganizationCode>ANOTHERORG</OrganizationCode>
                  </OrganizationAddress>
                  </OrganizationAddressCollection>
              </Shipment>
            </UniversalShipment>
              </Body>
            </UniversalInterchange>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start using linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Container> containers = doc.Descendants("Container")
                .Select(x => new Container()
                {
                    commodityCode = (string)x.Element("Commodity").Element("Code"),
                    description = (string)x.Element("Commodity").Element("Description"),
                    containerCode = (string)x.Element("ContainerType").Element("Code")
                }).ToList();

            var firstTwoDigits = containers.GroupBy(x => int.Parse(x.containerCode.Substring(0, 2))).ToList();

            foreach (var firstTwoDigit in firstTwoDigits)
            {
                int numberOfItems = firstTwoDigit.Key * firstTwoDigit.Count();
                foreach (Container container in firstTwoDigit)
                {
                    if ((container.commodityCode == "XYZ"))
                    {
                    }

                }
            }
                    
        }
    }
    public class Container
    {
        public string commodityCode { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string containerCode { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }

    }
}
```